# ImportRange Remove Entire Row

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the `importrange` function which pulls data from a Master sheet to the Child sheet. The issue I am having is when a row in the Master sheet gets removed, 'static' cells for that referencing row in the Child sheet does not get removed as well.

For more context on 'static' cells, these are cells that are manually entered in the Child sheet.

Example:

Master Sheet: A1 = Test, A2 = Test1, A3 = Test3

Child Sheet:

- A1 = importrange("XXXX","MasterSheet!"A:A")
- B1 = Some manually entered text

Upon removing of row 1 from the Master Sheet1, ChildSheet!B1 value is now for Test1 but ideally should be blank. How can I get the entire row to be removed upon changes from the Master Sheet?

Comment: Do you mean `ChildSheet!B1` or `ChildSheet!A1`? What makes you think that there should be a blank row? If it no longer exists in the master sheet then it won't import.

Comment: Hi Rafa, yes, if it doesn't exist on the master it won't import but if I entered manual data in the Child sheet for a particular row that references the imported row, it will not remove this manual data upon deletion from the master sheet

Comment: Please share a sample of your sheet, with non-sensitive data, to make it easier to help you.  This may require using code for a solution, since I don't think that your manually entered data on ChildSheet can't be "removed" by a formula approach.